# How to hide list of combobox whose DropDownStyle is set to simple?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, drop-down-menu

I need to have drop down style of ComboBox set to simple because I have to hide the arrow that shows when style is set to ComboBox or DropDownList, this ComboBox will be disabled. I need to bind some items to this ComboBox via binding source, but the value is selected based on some properties calculated on a press of some button, that is why I need it disabled and without the arrow.


With this, because item is automatically selected, I need to hide the list that shows below. Is it possible to hide the list and how?

Answer (score 1):

Try this technique..

Drag a **LABEL control** and change the back color as same as the color of the form and make the **TEXT** of LABEL into "" and the size of label must equal to the size of list of Dropdown box.

Then you can hide and show the **LABEL**..

:)

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that control was in a layoutGrid and had Dock set to Fill. After I undocked it, then I was able to set height of the control, and I set it to 21 so now the bottom list can't be seen.
Thanks!